# command 'gedit' is available in /usr/bin/gedit '

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I just cannot resolve this error:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
command 'gedit' is available in the `/usr/bin/gedit`
```

How do I master for courigé not really Ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! «How do I master for courigé not really Ubuntu» Could you clarify this?

Comment: Your PATH is broken. Before doing anything else, you should go back to your PATH adjustments and correct those.

Answer (score 5):

The error message has the answer. Gedit is not in your PATH

Specify the full path:

```
/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc
```

or better, add the path to your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

or better, for a permanent fix, see [How to Add a Directory to my Path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

But `/usr/bin` should be in your path already so your system seems broken... What did you do before this happened?

Comment: I try to install spark if you can help me

Comment: @lyly please ask a new question